# Good definition of the Gamma function

Tags: analysis, definition, gamma-function

I have an existential doubt regarding the good definition of the Gamma function $\Gamma(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$, this refers to the convergence of the following integral, I have thought of using the limit comparison criterion with $g(t)=\dfrac{1}{t^2}$ that is
$$
\lim_{t\to +\infty} \dfrac{t^{x-1}e^{-t}}{\frac{1}{t^2}}=\lim_{t\to +\infty} \dfrac{t^{x+1}}{e^t}=0.
$$
This limit does not depend on the sign that $x$ takes or does it? That way I check that $\Gamma(x)$ with $x\in\mathbb R$ is well defined. I know that it is not defined for negative integers but I don't know where the error is, even so after finding my error how can I prove that $\Gamma(x)$ is not defined for negative integers?

[image]

Comment: The criterion only tells the convergence at $\infty$. What about $0$?

Comment: @user58697 So the only way to prove its good definition is to split the integral $\int_0^{+\infty}=\int_0^{1}+\int_1^{+\infty}$ then analyze each one? Is there a different way to prove good definition?

Comment: This is exactly the way. Moreover, you obtain a Mittag-Leffler decomposition for the Gamma function in the process, since the improper integral defines an analytic function, and the proper has poles at all negative integers. Expand the exponent in the proper part in Taylor series and integrate term-by-term.

Comment: @Daigaku no Bakú That sounds quite interesting, could you give me some reference in the way you tell me?

Comment: I personally learned this from my mathematical physics lecturer and a booklet "Вычеты и их приложения" (Residues and their applications) by Gelfond, which appears to be not translated into English (or any other language), but this is very standard material you will surely find in any mathematics textbook introducing the Gamma function. What specifically are you interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me write a slightly more detailed answer. First of all, as noted by @user58697, you correctly deduce that the integral does not diverge **at infinity**. This criterion tells you nothing of divergence for other reasons (poles at finite points). To see that the integral has poles at all negative integers, divide it into two parts:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt=\left(\int_{0}^{1}+\int_{1}^{\infty}\right) t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
The second integral converges for any value of $x$, and defines, in fact, an entire function. Expand the exponent in the first integral into Taylor series:
$$\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kt^k}{k!} dt+\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{ -t }dt=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1+k} dt +\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{ -t }dt=$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k }{k! (x+k)}+\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{ -t }dt$$

You've obtained an expression that has a pole at every negative integer.

Comment: You may say $z$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I literally copied the LaTeX code for the calculation from my notes, and in my notes the variable is called $z$, not $x$. I hope that won't cause misunderstanding.

Comment: Well, you can just edit the answer. It takes a few seconds.

Comment: It takes more than a few seconds to change all $z$'s to $x$'s
UPD. Edited.

Comment: That is why I suggested to write $z$ in place of that single $x$. ;)